# Unable to find the requested Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: c#, postgresql, windows-services, provider

Its a very specific error message, but I can't find the problem.

I have a windows service that needs to communicate with a database, for that I do the following:

```
string provider = "Devart.Data.PostgreSql";
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);
```

But it crashes, giving me this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework
>   Data Provider.  It may not be installed.    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)

I tried to move the Devart.Data.PostgreSql.dll to the bin folder, but the results are the same.

Then I checked my machine.config, and I have this:

```
<add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" 
     invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql"
     description="Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL" 
     type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Version=7.4.506.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
```

So it looks right, I didn't found any empty  tags, found that in other SO posts, saying that removing those tags when empty could solve the problem, but I didnt had any.

So I don't know what is the problem.

I also created a console project, which uses the same .Net version, and with the exact code:

```
string provider = "Devart.Data.PostgreSql";
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);
```

And it works. Does anyone knows what could it be?

Comment: Where does the error occur?  Is it at the line DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);

Comment: Yes. The error occurs at that line.

Comment: And you have added the Devart.Data.PostgreSql.dll as a reference to your project?

Comment: No. Both of my projects don't reference Devart.Data.PostgreSql.dll.